# Retrieve Credentials in a loop using c#

Tags: c#, windows, credentials

I searched for a way to retrieve all Credentials in a loop.

**[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741424/retrieve-credentials-from-windows-credentials-store-using-c-sharp)** post helped me to retrieve them all. But there are many credentials and they also change.

**So is there a way to retrieve them by getting a list of all available credetialnames and then loop through this list to do further stuff?**

Atm it's really static like

```
public void GetCredentials()
{
    var cm = new Credential();

    cm.Target = "TERMSRV/servername.xy"; 
    //(Credentialname - static | i want to enumerate this)

    if (!cm.Exists())
    {
            MessageBox.Show("not found", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
    cm.Load();

    MessageBox.Show(cm.Username + " - " + cm.Password, "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

}
```

**EDIT:** Im not searching for informations how loop works :D I am looking for a property of `credentials` that contains all available credentials in a kind of a list...

Comment: By looking at the source code of the library, the CredEnumerate is not exposed in the current implementation. May be you can get the source code and make those changes if you want.

Comment: where can i look for this ? im not the c# crack^^ still practicing :D but... when does practice stops.. guess never :D

Comment: Source code is available [here](http://credentialmanagement.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)