# How to Save Network Credentials with C#

Tags: c#, networking, networkcredentials

This code needs to be performed for my work.

```
string filePath = "\\\\192.168.7.202\\Sample\sample.log"
var accessControlList = Directory.GetAccessControl( filePath );
```

Unfortunately, this code can't work without a Network Credentials.
so the Network Credential for 192.168.7.202 has to be added  on a computer I use.

**Can anyone know how to add Netowrk Credentials by C# script,
with its IP Address, Username, and Password?**

This is my code, but doesn't work.....

```
string ipAddress = "192.168.7.202";
string username = "Administrator";
string password = "abcd";

NetworkCredential netCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, ipAddress);

CredentialCache theNetCache = new CredentialCache();
theNetCache.Add("192.168.7.202", 3389, "Basic", netCredential);

string filePath = "\\\\192.168.7.202\\Sample\sample.log"
var accessControlList = Directory.GetAccessControl( filePath ); **//Error occur without Credential**
```

May not have to keep the Credential permanently,
at least need it for the Directory.GetAccessControl(filePath).

Can anyone give me a solution please...?

FYI, adding Credential of 192.168.7.202 to the Red box by myself makes Directory.GetAccessControl works well.
Hope I can do it on C# script..

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741424/retrieve-credentials-from-windows-credentials-store-using-c-sharp

Comment: https://github.com/AdysTech/CredentialManager

Comment: Another option would be use to the net use command to map the path with credentials to a drive and access it that way.

Comment: CodeCaster// well, the links are not really about my case... thanks though.

Comment: mike z // are you talking about the command we use in CMD?