# How to remove Web Microsoft.CredentialManager

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a problem when test with my project, After error, I must remove Web Credentials,
I tried research to remove Web Credentials by a Winform application, I only open it in form,
How to remove first app in Web Credentials by develop.

[image]

Comment: See if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17747020/6138713) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement/)

It is more detailed at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741424/retrieve-credentials-from-windows-credentials-store-using-c-sharp).

Comment: Prolem when i want create a tool to remove it faster. So this way don't slove issues bro.

Comment: Thanks your reply, i will try it, i not yet up vote in myquestion

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagemen/. nuget package. There is no professional C# code to remove such credential. Using the above nuget pacvkage you will be easily able to remove the web credentials.