# How to search for Windows dynamic link library that contains a windows api function

Tags: java, windows, dll, jna

I'm using the JNA to interact with the Windows API.

I want to use the [`LogonUserW` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw) in the `WinBase.h` header. In order to load it using the JNA's [`Native.load`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.java.dev.jna/jna/5.8.0/com/sun/jna/Native.html#load-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-), I need to know the dynamic link library's name.

For example, [`CredReadW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-credreadw) is in the `WinCred.h` header, and I found through examples that the function is provided by `advapi32.dll`, so I was able to load the function with:

```java
// WinCrypt is my own interface. I'm not sure why it's WinCrypt instead of WinCred,
// but that's what I saw in other examples.
Native.load("Advapi32", WinCrypt.class);
```

[Here's the example this is based on.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63426694/11389598)

Do I really need to use DUMPBIN to inspect every dll in Windows to find it? I would've hoped that Microsoft offered a better way to find these.

Answer (score 0):

Agh nvm the page itself has a table showing you the library. Just search for the string "Advapi32"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw