# How does Microsoft Dynamic CRM Plugin Registration Tool store site's password?

Tags: dynamics-crm

When I connect to my CRM site using Plugin Registration Tool, I can choose to store my password so that the next time I login, I no longer need to type it.

Does anyone know how and where Plugin Registration Tool stores my password? Surely they cannot store them in a irreversible way, can they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password is stored in the **Windows Credential Manager**.

More info about how to store and retrieve stored passwords in the Windows Vault here:

[How do I store and retrieve credentials from the Windows Vault credential manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221245/how-do-i-store-and-retrieve-credentials-from-the-windows-vault-credential-manage)