# Use the windows credential manager in Java to get credentials for authentication into git and other services

Tags: java, windows, credential-manager

At the moment we store the passwords in a plain text file to sign into git and other services. We want to finaly get rid of it and use the windows credential manager. The only problem we are facing is that I don't seem to find a solution to do it java.

I already looked at the following topics:

- [How do I store and retrieve credentials from the Windows Vault credential manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221245/how-do-i-store-and-retrieve-credentials-from-the-windows-vault-credential-manage)
- [How to retrieve username and password from windows vault using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233269/how-to-retrieve-username-and-password-from-windows-vault-using-java)

But for me they don't give me clear answer which api to use. If you could help me on my way to access this credential manager that would be awesome.

Answer (score 5):

We actually have the same issue come up in our company.
We have a Java Client Application running on windows and the customer asked for a password saving functionality. So we turned to the windows credential manager for that. So much for the background.

It seems that there is no java library for that, although there might be one.
(btw: your second link is a 404).

Thus the way we planned is to write java code using the java native interface with C accessing the windows credential manager.
BUT I found [this library](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-authentication-library-for-java/), which has a [java class written for accessing the windows credential manager](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-authentication-library-for-java/blob/master/storage/src/main/java/com/microsoft/alm/storage/windows/internal/CredManagerBackedSecureStore.java).

I think, this might help.

Answer (score 4):

Cheese.....don't use that library.

A) It's broken

B) It's needlessly convoluted (XML backed credential object? srsly?)

C) It depends on some vulnerable libraries. Don't do that to your customers. Just don't. It's already bad enough that they're stuck with Java.

Drop these two files into your project, and use them like so:

```java
    WinCred wc = new WinCred();
    // Create a credential
    wc.setCredential("Application Name", "Username", "Password");
    // Get a credential
    Credential cred = wc.getCredential("Application Name");
    String username = cred.username;
    String password = cred.password;

    System.out.println(username);
    System.out.println(password);
    // Delete a credential
    wc.deleteCredential("Application Name")
```

Put this in your build.gradle:

```
    implementation('net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.11.0')
    implementation('net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.11.0')
```

First file:

```java
package wincred;

import com.sun.jna.LastErrorException;
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class exposes functions from credential manager on Windows platform
 * via JNA.
 *
 * Please refer to MSDN documentations for each method usage pattern
 */
interface CredAdvapi32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    CredAdvapi32 INSTANCE = (CredAdvapi32) Native.load("Advapi32",
            CredAdvapi32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
    /**
     * CredRead flag
     */
    int CRED_FLAGS_PROMPT_NOW = 0x0002;
    int CRED_FLAGS_USERNAME_TARGET = 0x0004;

    /**
     * Type of Credential
     */
    int CRED_TYPE_GENERIC = 1;
    int CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_PASSWORD = 2;
    int CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_CERTIFICATE = 3;
    int CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_VISIBLE_PASSWORD = 4;
    int CRED_TYPE_GENERIC_CERTIFICATE = 5;
    int CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_EXTENDED = 6;
    int CRED_TYPE_MAXIMUM = 7;       // Maximum supported cred type
    int CRED_TYPE_MAXIMUM_EX = CRED_TYPE_MAXIMUM + 1000;

    /**
     * CredWrite flag
     */
    int CRED_PRESERVE_CREDENTIAL_BLOB = 0x1;

    /**
     * Values of the Credential Persist field
     */
    int CRED_PERSIST_NONE = 0;
    int CRED_PERSIST_SESSION = 1;
    int CRED_PERSIST_LOCAL_MACHINE = 2;
    int CRED_PERSIST_ENTERPRISE = 3;

    /**
     * Credential attributes
     *
     * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374790(v=vs.85).aspx
     *
     * typedef struct _CREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE {
     *   LPTSTR Keyword;
     *   DWORD  Flags;
     *   DWORD  ValueSize;
     *   LPBYTE Value;
     * } CREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE, *PCREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE;
     *
     */
    class CREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE extends Structure {

        public static class ByReference extends CREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE implements Structure.ByReference { }

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("Keyword",
                    "Flags",
                    "ValueSize",
                    "Value");
        }

        /**
         *    Name of the application-specific attribute. Names should be of the form <CompanyName>_<Name>.
         *    This member cannot be longer than CRED_MAX_STRING_LENGTH (256) characters.
         */
        public String Keyword;

        /**
         *   Identifies characteristics of the credential attribute. This member is reserved and should be originally
         *   initialized as zero and not otherwise altered to permit future enhancement.
         */
        public int Flags;

        /**
         *   Length of Value in bytes. This member cannot be larger than CRED_MAX_VALUE_SIZE (256).
         */
        public int ValueSize;

        /**
         *   Data associated with the attribute. By convention, if Value is a text string, then Value should not
         *   include the trailing zero character and should be in UNICODE.
         *
         *   Credentials are expected to be portable. The application should take care to ensure that the data in
         *   value is portable. It is the responsibility of the application to define the byte-endian and alignment
         *   of the data in Value.
         */
        public Pointer Value;
    }

    /**
     * Pointer to {@See CREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE} struct
     */
    class PCREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE extends Structure {

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Collections.singletonList("credential_attribute");
        }

        public PCREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE() {
            super();
        }

        public PCREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE(byte[] data) {
            super(new Memory(data.length));
            getPointer().write(0, data, 0, data.length);
            read();
        }

        public PCREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE(Pointer memory) {
            super(memory);
            read();
        }

        public Pointer credential_attribute;
    }

    /**
     * The CREDENTIAL structure contains an individual credential
     *
     * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374788(v=vs.85).aspx
     *
     * typedef struct _CREDENTIAL {
     *   DWORD                 Flags;
     *   DWORD                 Type;
     *   LPTSTR                TargetName;
     *   LPTSTR                Comment;
     *   FILETIME              LastWritten;
     *   DWORD                 CredentialBlobSize;
     *   LPBYTE                CredentialBlob;
     *   DWORD                 Persist;
     *   DWORD                 AttributeCount;
     *   PCREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE Attributes;
     *   LPTSTR                TargetAlias;
     *   LPTSTR                UserName;
     * } CREDENTIAL, *PCREDENTIAL;
     */
    class CREDENTIAL extends Structure {

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("Flags",
                    "Type",
                    "TargetName",
                    "Comment",
                    "LastWritten",
                    "CredentialBlobSize",
                    "CredentialBlob",
                    "Persist",
                    "AttributeCount",
                    "Attributes",
                    "TargetAlias",
                    "UserName");
        }

        public CREDENTIAL() {
            super();
        }

        public CREDENTIAL(final int size) {
            super(new Memory(size));
        }

        public CREDENTIAL(Pointer memory) {
            super(memory);
            read();
        }

        /**
         *   A bit member that identifies characteristics of the credential. Undefined bits should be initialized
         *   as zero and not otherwise altered to permit future enhancement.
         *
         *   See MSDN doc for all possible flags
         */
        public int Flags;

        /**
         *   The type of the credential. This member cannot be changed after the credential is created.
         *
         *   See MSDN doc for all possible types
         */
        public int Type;

        /**
         *   The name of the credential. The TargetName and Type members uniquely identify the credential.
         *   This member cannot be changed after the credential is created. Instead, the credential with the old
         *   name should be deleted and the credential with the new name created.
         *
         *   See MSDN doc for additional requirement
         */
        public String TargetName;

        /**
         *   A string comment from the user that describes this credential. This member cannot be longer than
         *   CRED_MAX_STRING_LENGTH (256) characters.
         */
        public String Comment;

        /**
         *   The time, in Coordinated Universal Time (Greenwich Mean Time), of the last modification of the credential.
         *   For write operations, the value of this member is ignored.
         */
        public WinBase.FILETIME LastWritten;

        /**
         *   The size, in bytes, of the CredentialBlob member. This member cannot be larger than
         *   CRED_MAX_CREDENTIAL_BLOB_SIZE (512) bytes.
         */
        public int CredentialBlobSize;

        /**
         *   Secret data for the credential. The CredentialBlob member can be both read and written.
         *   If the Type member is CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_PASSWORD, this member contains the plaintext Unicode password
         *   for UserName. The CredentialBlob and CredentialBlobSize members do not include a trailing zero character.
         *   Also, for CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_PASSWORD, this member can only be read by the authentication packages.
         *
         *   If the Type member is CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_CERTIFICATE, this member contains the clear test
         *   Unicode PIN for UserName. The CredentialBlob and CredentialBlobSize members do not include a trailing
         *   zero character. Also, this member can only be read by the authentication packages.
         *
         *   If the Type member is CRED_TYPE_GENERIC, this member is defined by the application.
         *   Credentials are expected to be portable. Applications should ensure that the data in CredentialBlob is
         *   portable. The application defines the byte-endian and alignment of the data in CredentialBlob.
         */
        public Pointer CredentialBlob;

        /**
         *   Defines the persistence of this credential. This member can be read and written.
         *
         *   See MSDN doc for all possible values
         */
        public int Persist;

        /**
         *   The number of application-defined attributes to be associated with the credential. This member can be
         *   read and written. Its value cannot be greater than CRED_MAX_ATTRIBUTES (64).
         */
        public int AttributeCount;

        /**
         *   Application-defined attributes that are associated with the credential. This member can be read
         *   and written.
         */
        //notTODO: Need to make this into array
        public CREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE.ByReference Attributes;

        /**
         *   Alias for the TargetName member. This member can be read and written. It cannot be longer than
         *   CRED_MAX_STRING_LENGTH (256) characters.
         *
         *   If the credential Type is CRED_TYPE_GENERIC, this member can be non-NULL, but the credential manager
         *   ignores the member.
         */
        public String TargetAlias;

        /**
         *   The user name of the account used to connect to TargetName.
         *   If the credential Type is CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_PASSWORD, this member can be either a DomainName\UserName
         *   or a UPN.
         *
         *   If the credential Type is CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_CERTIFICATE, this member must be a marshaled certificate
         *   reference created by calling CredMarshalCredential with a CertCredential.
         *
         *   If the credential Type is CRED_TYPE_GENERIC, this member can be non-NULL, but the credential manager
         *   ignores the member.
         *
         *   This member cannot be longer than CRED_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH (513) characters.
         */
        public String UserName;
    }

    /**
     *  Pointer to {@see CREDENTIAL} struct
     */
    class PCREDENTIAL extends Structure {

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Collections.singletonList("credential");
        }

        public PCREDENTIAL() {
            super();
        }

        public PCREDENTIAL(byte[] data) {
            super(new Memory(data.length));
            getPointer().write(0, data, 0, data.length);
            read();
        }

        public PCREDENTIAL(Pointer memory) {
            super(memory);
            read();
        }

        public Pointer credential;
    }

    /**
     * The CredRead function reads a credential from the user's credential set.
     *
     * The credential set used is the one associated with the logon session of the current token.
     * The token must not have the user's SID disabled.
     *
     * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374804(v=vs.85).aspx
     *
     * @param targetName
     *      String that contains the name of the credential to read.
     * @param type
     *      Type of the credential to read. Type must be one of the CRED_TYPE_* defined types.
     * @param flags
     *      Currently reserved and must be zero.
     * @param pcredential
     *      Out - Pointer to a single allocated block buffer to return the credential.
     *      Any pointers contained within the buffer are pointers to locations within this single allocated block.
     *      The single returned buffer must be freed by calling <code>CredFree</code>.
     *
     * @return
     *      True if CredRead succeeded, false otherwise
     *
     * @throws LastErrorException
     *      GetLastError
     */
    boolean CredRead(String targetName, int type, int flags, PCREDENTIAL pcredential) throws LastErrorException;

    /**
     * The CredWrite function creates a new credential or modifies an existing credential in the user's credential set.
     * The new credential is associated with the logon session of the current token. The token must not have the
     * user's security identifier (SID) disabled.
     *
     * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375187(v=vs.85).aspx
     *
     * @param credential
     *      A CREDENTIAL structure to be written.
     * @param flags
     *      Flags that control the function's operation. The following flag is defined.
     *      CRED_PRESERVE_CREDENTIAL_BLOB:
     *          The credential BLOB from an existing credential is preserved with the same
     *          credential name and credential type. The CredentialBlobSize of the passed
     *          in Credential structure must be zero.
     *
     * @return
     *      True if CredWrite succeeded, false otherwise
     *
     * @throws LastErrorException
     *      GetLastError
     */
    boolean CredWrite(CREDENTIAL credential, int flags) throws LastErrorException;

    /**
     * The CredDelete function deletes a credential from the user's credential set. The credential set used is the one
     * associated with the logon session of the current token. The token must not have the user's SID disabled.
     *
     * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374787(v=vs.85).aspx
     *
     * @param targetName
     *      String that contains the name of the credential to read.
     * @param type
     *      Type of the credential to delete. Must be one of the CRED_TYPE_* defined types. For a list of the
     *      defined types, see the Type member of the CREDENTIAL structure.
     *      If the value of this parameter is CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_EXTENDED, this function can delete a credential that
     *      specifies a user name when there are multiple credentials for the same target. The value of the TargetName
     *      parameter must specify the user name as Target|UserName.
     * @param flags
     *      Reserved and must be zero.
     *
     * @return
     *      True if CredDelete succeeded, false otherwise
     *
     * @throws LastErrorException
     *      GetLastError
     */
    boolean CredDelete(String targetName, int type, int flags) throws LastErrorException;

    /**
     * The CredFree function frees a buffer returned by any of the credentials management functions.
     *
     * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374796(v=vs.85).aspx
     *
     * @param credential
     *      Pointer to CREDENTIAL to be freed
     *
     * @throws LastErrorException
     *      GetLastError
     */
    void CredFree(Pointer credential) throws LastErrorException;
}
```

The other file:

```java
package wincred;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import com.sun.jna.LastErrorException;
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

public class WinCred implements CredAdvapi32 {

  public static <T> T coalesce(final T maybeNullValue, final T nonNullValue) {
    return maybeNullValue == null ? nonNullValue : maybeNullValue;
  }

  public class Credential {
    public String target;
    public String username;
    public String password;

    public Credential(String target, String username, String password) {
      this.target = coalesce(target, "");
      this.username = coalesce(username, "");
      this.password = coalesce(password, "");
    }
  }

  public Credential getCredential(String target) {
    PCREDENTIAL pcredMem = new PCREDENTIAL();

    try {
    if (CredRead(target, 1, 0, pcredMem)) {
      CREDENTIAL credMem = new CREDENTIAL(pcredMem.credential);
      byte[] passwordBytes = credMem.CredentialBlob.getByteArray(0, credMem.CredentialBlobSize);

      String password = new String(passwordBytes, Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"));
      Credential cred = new WinCred.Credential(credMem.TargetName, credMem.UserName, password);
      return cred;
    } else {
      int err = Native.getLastError();
      throw new LastErrorException(err);
    }
    } finally {
      CredFree(pcredMem.credential);
    }
  }

  public boolean setCredential(String target, String userName, String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    CREDENTIAL credMem = new CREDENTIAL();

    credMem.Flags = 0;
    credMem.TargetName = target;
    credMem.Type = CRED_TYPE_GENERIC;
    credMem.UserName = userName;
    credMem.AttributeCount = 0;
    credMem.Persist = CRED_PERSIST_ENTERPRISE;
    byte[] bpassword = password.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    credMem.CredentialBlobSize = (int) bpassword.length;
    credMem.CredentialBlob = getPointer(bpassword);
    if (!CredWrite(credMem, 0)) {
      int err = Native.getLastError();
      throw new LastErrorException(err);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  }

  public boolean deleteCredential(String target) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if (!CredDelete(target, CRED_TYPE_GENERIC, 0)) {
      int err = Native.getLastError();
      throw new LastErrorException(err);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  }

  private static Pointer getPointer(byte[] array) {
    Pointer p = new Memory(array.length);
    p.write(0, array, 0, array.length);

    return p;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean CredRead(String targetName, int type, int flags, PCREDENTIAL pcredential) throws LastErrorException {
    synchronized (INSTANCE) {
      return INSTANCE.CredRead(targetName, type, flags, pcredential);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean CredWrite(CREDENTIAL credential, int flags) throws LastErrorException {
    synchronized (INSTANCE) {
      return INSTANCE.CredWrite(credential, flags);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean CredDelete(String targetName, int type, int flags) throws LastErrorException {
    synchronized (INSTANCE) {
      return INSTANCE.CredDelete(targetName, type, flags);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void CredFree(Pointer credential) throws LastErrorException {
    synchronized (INSTANCE) {
      INSTANCE.CredFree(credential);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it reads only Generic credentials and not Windows... also it does not retrieve comment..

Answer (score 3):

Looking for a way to access the Windows Credential Manager in java myself, I found that the Microsoft library in [Jonas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68469535/4666576) provides a simple way to do that:

```
CredManagerBackedCredentialStore credentialStore = new CredManagerBackedCredentialStore();
Credential cred = credentialStore.get("MyCredentialManagerKey");
```

The dependency I used was `implementation("com.microsoft.alm:auth-secure-storage:0.6.4")` and the resulting `Credential` object allows me to read the user/password. Also, the `CredManagerBackedCredentialStore` object allows to add entries into the Windows Credential Manager.

Comment: It seems to be working for 'Generic Credentials' in win cred manager, but does not work for 'Windows Credentials'