# Is it possible to use Windows impersonation through a web application to access PowerBI Report Server

Tags: spring, windows, iframe, powerbi, impersonation

Basically, I want to know if its possible through a web application whether it's possible to access the on-prem version of Power BI Report server through different Windows credentials from the host user.

Example: I sign into my machine as 'Harry'. A user account 'Barry' has access to the Power BI Report server. 'Harry' signs into the web application and through the web application, there's a link that directs to the Report Server. Is it possible that when clicking the hyperlink to get directed, the user will be able to view the reports signed in as 'Barry' despite the host machine being 'Harry'?

I've been using a Spring web application and implementing Waffle to do impersonation of a seperate AD, however I haven't gotten the results I wanted. I also heard one thing about using iframes to get the impersonated credentials to the Report Server, although I'm not too sure on its validity. Also, since it's non-cloud/on-prem I won't be able to publish and use the embedded feature of Power BI. At least, I believe so.

The desired end result is that the user will be able to have access to the reports of the on-prem Power BI Report Server using a 'generic'/impersonated Windows account. Would this be possible?

I've been using a Spring web application and implementing Waffle to do impersonation of a seperate AD, however I haven't gotten the results I wanted. I also heard one thing about using iframes to get the impersonated credentials to the Report Server, although I'm not too sure on its validity.

I've tried the use of iframes in hopes of having the credentials of the impersonated account passed to the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

This is regular Windows Authentication.  The user will only use their logged-in identity unless you configure the report server to only use HTTP Basic Auth, and force the user to provide alternative credentials, or you inject an alternate Windows credential in the user's client credential store.

But *why* are you trying to do that?

Comment: I want to see if it's possible. There's a lot of info on the cloud, but I'm using the onprem version. What I want is to know if, through a web application, it's possible to allow the user to access the reports on the server using a Windows account separate from the user. Considering it's not using the cloud, how would I inject Windows credentials into the client credential store?

Comment: For accessing the credential store see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221245/how-do-i-store-and-retrieve-credentials-from-the-windows-vault-credential-manage